# Will there be any new additional changes to the Constantinople Upgrade in Feb 2019 vs the delayed one from Jan?

Tags: upgrading, constantinople

With the upcoming Constantinople Feb 2019 upgrade, will there be any other new changes that wasn't present in the delayed Jan 2019 upgrade? All I know is they fixed the bug they found that delayed it, but was there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

They will slash EIP1283 out. Nothing more, nothing less.

> > EIP-1283, is based on an earlier proposal EIP 1087 that was authored by Nick Johnson. EIP-1283 is called, Net gas metering for SSTORE without dirty maps. A long, confusing sounding EIP name that makes it possible for multiple updates to use the same storage slot within a transaction to reduce cost. This can be done because the transaction doesn’t write to disk until the end of a transaction.